# How to get a file's very top parent folder in SharePoint 2013 document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-set, folder

If there is a file in a document library in this structure:

Document Library

-DocumentSet

--Folder1

---Folder2

----File

How do I get the reference to DocumentSet from the file with server side object model?

Comment: None that I am aware of. You will need to break the URL apart. The item url is basically list/folder[x]/item.

Comment: Bunzab - thanks for your suggestion. It led me to the solution. If you rewrite as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to break the URL apart. The item url is basically list/folder[x]/item.

Credits to [Bunzab](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/24490/bunzab)